# replace method not working in browser but working in console.log

Tags: javascript, wordpress, browser, replace, console.log

I'm trying to replace multiple occurrences in a **Wordpress** website, so here's what I did:

```
window.onload = init;

function init()
{
    // get all the divs which have specific class names
    let divElems = 
    document.querySelectorAll(".vc_custom_heading.white.vc_gitem-post-data.vc_gitem-post-data-source-post_title");

    // loop on the divs
    for(let i = 0 ; i < divElems.length ; i++)
    {
        // get the first child of the div : a <h2>
        let titleElem = divElems[i].childNodes[0];
        // get the first child of the title : a <a>
        let linkElem  = titleElem.childNodes[0];
        // get the text content of the link
        let text      = linkElem.textContent;

        // replace the word test by nothing
        text = text.replace(/test/g, '');
        // all the occurrences of test have been removed in the console.log, but not in browser
        console.log(text);
    }
};
```

But weirdly, the replace method works fine in the **console.log** (I can see that the test word has been removed), but nothing changed in the **browser** page !

Does someone have an idea ? :)

ArbreMojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just updating the variable value so it won't update the actual element content. To make it work, update the element content by simply updating [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

```
text = text.replace(/test/g, '');
linkElem.textContent = text;
```